# How do I create a check for this code?

Tags: c++, constraints

I'm trying to make it so that the code checks if the user input is between (and including) 10 and 100.

Being so used to just single inputs, I'm having trouble since it's an array...

```
int main()
{
    int numlist[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter # " << i + 1 << " : ";

        // here is where I am going wrong... 

        if ((numlist[i] <= 100) && (numlist[i] >= 10))
        {
            cin >> numlist[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't you put the input statement `cin >> numlist[i]` **before** the test `if ((numlist[i] <= 100) && (numlist[i] >= 10))` ?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you want to do something like this:

```
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  cin >> temp;
  if ((temp <= 100) && (temp >= 10))
    numlist[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a slightly different way you could do this, you might consider a `vector` instead of an array, and read the data with an `istream_iterator` along with a standard algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> numlist;

std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                    std::back_inserter(numlist), 
                    [](int i)->bool { return i<10 || i > 100; });
```

Edit: I guess since I'm using C++11 lambda, I could also use the C++11 `copy_if`, which expresses the intent a bit more directly:

```
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
             std::istream_iterator<int>(),
             std::back_inserter(numlist), 
             [](int i)->bool { return i>=10 && i<=100; });
```

As far as "clever" goes, that's not the intent at all -- rather, what's desired is a simple, direct expression of the original intent: to copy (filtered) data from standard input to a container. It does take a bit to get used to the idea of treating files as containers (especially ones like `std::cin`, which is normally interactive), but ultimately a file is a sequence, and istream_iterator/ostream_iterator just let you treat them like other sequences.

Comment: Clever... But I just think if you want a filter, C++ is just not the best language to express this in...

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can't check a value that you haven't even read (from the user).
To constraint the input you must check the input after cin inside a do while loop, as long as it doesn't satisfy the constraint.

```
do
{
    //you might cout here
    cin >> numlist[i];
}
while ((numlist[i] > 100) || (numlist[i] < 10));
```

Comment: You might want to also `++i` somewhere, but otherwise, I think this is closest to what the OP asked fo.

Comment: ++i has to be outside this loop, I gave only a code to taking same input as long as it does not meets constraint.